# Rails: implement sharing blogs; has_many with STI: undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

Just started using STI with a Rails 4 project. Suppose I have `User` and `Blog`, and `User` can share his non-public blogs to some other users as `editors` or `normal viewers`.

It doesn't make sense for me to put `type` column in `users` table, because in the project, the user is associated with not just `blogs`, but also things like `posts`. (The blogs here are more like a platform, and posts are articles. Just an idea here, could be other two things).

So I used another model called `BlogUserAssociation` to manage the above sharing relationship. Basically this model contains a `type` column, and I have `BlogEditorAssociation` and `BlogViewerAssociation` inherited from it. (Name is a bit clunky.) **First question**, is this a recommended way to handle the "sharing" situation?

With the above thought, I have:

```
# blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :blog_user_associations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :editors, through: :blog_editor_associations, source: :user
    has_many :allowed_viewers, through: :blog_viewer_associations, source: :user # STI
    ...
```

And

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :blog_user_associations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :editable_blogs, through: :blog_editor_associations, source: :blog
    has_many :blogs_shared_for_view, through: :blog_viewer_associations, source: :blog
    ...
```

But when I tried to test this with Rspec,

```
it { should have_many(:editors).through(:blog_editor_associations).source(:user) }
```

I got the error `undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass`

I believe this is because I didn't say `has_many blog_editor_associations` in `User`. But I thought since `blog_editor_associations` inherits from `blog_viewer_associations`, I don't have to say `has_many` again for the sub-model. So **is there a reason for not automatically bind `has_many` to sub-models?**

Answer (score 1):

STI seems like overkill for this situation. I prefer to add an attribute to the association model and use scopes to retrieve collections, depending on the value of the attribute. For example, you could name the association model `BlogUser`, and add a boolean `can_edit` column.  A value of `true` indicates the user can edit the associated blog.

Then the models look like this:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_users
  has_many :users, through: :blog_users
  scope :editable, -> { where(blog_users: {can_edit: true}) }
end

 class BlogUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :blog
   belongs_to :user
 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :blog_users
   has_many :blogs, through: :blog_users
   scope :editors, -> { where(blog_users: {can_edit: true}) }
 end
```

So `user.blogs` retrieves all blogs associated with the user, and `user.blogs.editable` retrieves all blogs that the user can edit. `blog.users` retrieves all users associated with the blog, and `blog.users.editors` retrieves all users who can edit the blog.

Some tests to demonstrate:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe "A user with no associated blogs" do
    let(:user) { User.create! }
    it "has no blogs" do
      expect(user.blogs.empty?).to be true
      expect(user.blogs.editable.empty?).to be true
    end
  end

  describe "A user with a non-editable blog association" do
    let(:user) { User.create! }
    let(:blog) { Blog.create! }
    before do
      user.blogs << blog
    end
    it "has one blog" do
      expect(user.blogs.count).to eq 1
    end
    it "has no editable blogs" do
      expect(user.blogs.editable.empty?).to be true
    end
  end

  describe "A user with an editable blog association" do
    let(:user) { User.create! }
    let(:blog) { Blog.create! }
    before do
      user.blog_users << BlogUser.new(blog: blog, user: user, can_edit: true)
    end
    it "has one blog" do
      expect(user.blogs.count).to eq 1
    end
    it "has one editable blog" do
      expect(user.blogs.editable.count).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding scope.  This does make code simpler. So you don't need any inheritance between BlogUser and Blog? How does scope work essentially? Just wanna wait to see if there's more suggestions. If not I will pick yours

Comment: So you mean adding a can_edit column to User table? What if I also have Post inside a blog (more like a platform) and a user can share its editability? Basically not just For Blog

Comment: Add the `can_edit` column to the BlogUser table. Take a look at the Rails Guide for more detail about scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

As to your question about the Post model, perhaps you could make that into another question.